# Get places and addresses from googlemap/openstreetmap to csv

Tags: csv, google-maps-api-3

My objective is to retrieve all the names of the places and their addresses from a nearbysearch query and put them into a csv or xls files.

I'm not a programmer and I'm just walking through the codes provided in googlemap api. I had ran the code below and is already fine since this can query all nearby places. However, instead of markers, I want the results to be in text or a downloadable xls/csv file with human-readable data.  How to do it? What to change?

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

Comment: The API saves your results in an object. Currently, I don't think there's a way to export the information in that object into a file. You might be able to save the information in a database, then export it from there but that might be more work than you want to invest. Alternatively, you can file a feature request for it [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list). Make sure to specify "Type-Enhancement" and 
"ApiType-Javascript3".

Comment: @not_a_bot I don't think this would be a bright idea for this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that what you want to achieve is not against the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

> **10.1.3 Restrictions against Copying or Data Export.**
>
> (a) No Unauthorized Copying, Modification, Creation of Derivative Works, or Display of the Content. You must not copy, translate, modify, or create a derivative work (including creating or contributing to a database) of, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof except as explicitly permitted under these Terms. For example, the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles; (ii) stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation; (iii) creating mailing lists or telemarketing lists based on the Content; or (iv) exporting, writing, or saving the Content to a third party's location-based platform or service.
>
> (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.

Comment: I missed that part. I'll not be using google maps then. thank you.